# Disposing of Object problem

Tags: c++, sockets

I have a problem freeing up memory of an object.Here is my code:

```
void Gateway::connect(DWORD dwIP)
{
    if (m_objRRSInterface != NULL)
    {
        //delete m_obj;
        m_obj = NULL;
    }

    m_obj = new objClass();
    m_obj->SetCallBackFn(fncp);

    if (m_obj->OpenSocket(dwIP, 3002))//3002 -port number
    {
        m_bConnect = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        m_bConnect = FALSE;     
        delete m_objRRSInterface;
        m_obj = NULL;
    }       
}
```

`objClass` is not my own class , it is imported from an external .dll.
`OpenSocket` method opens a socket connection on port 3002 and then I get all the data on fncp.

This function work's OK for the first time that i call it.
The problem appears when I call the function the second time.The problem that I have is that there is no `CloseSocket` method that i could call to reliable close the socket.

My question to you guys is that :Is there any method to dispose of an object and all this object dependences?
I've tried calling `delete m_obj;` but this hangs the application.

Comment: Can you connect it somewhere else (eg localhost + invalid port) and have it close its old connection before failing to reconnect?

Comment: @Ben I've just tried connecting to a dummy address before reinitializing the connection but still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should investigate about C++ destructors, which are meant to do what you are after.
This is where resources clean-up is usually done, but this is up to the programmer of the class. In other words, it is likely that `objClass` destructor does it resources clean-up there, but without reading the docs or the code, I cannot say.

The fact that your application hangs has nothing to do with C++ or destructors in themselves, anyway. Rather, it seems a question of the way you use your DLL, like calling `delete` at the wrong time, or before some manual clean-up.
But without knowing about `objClass` interface and semantics, I cannot help with this.

Comment: I didnt mean to say that my application hangs because of "delete".. I meant to say that i have a class written by someone else and I've tried to call "delete" and it doesn't work... my question is: is there any other way?

Comment: @Gabriel: the only other option that I can think of is a "clean-up" method. But actually, the destructor should do that, if it is implemented correctly. So, I doubt calling "clean-up" (if available) would change things that much. Anyway, without having the interface, it's hard to say.

Comment: @Gabriel: by the way, I was just trying to clarify things, I did not mean to criticize what you wrote! my fault if it was ambiguous...

Answer (score 1):

If there is no function to explicitly clean up the object or close the socket in the library documentation, does it automatically shut down the socket if there is no activity after a certain amount of time?

If you have a way of telling if the socket is still open, you could pass the object to a helper thread to delete it when it detects that the socket is closed.

The only other thing that I can think of is that it may be possible to reuse the object for the new connection.